# Google crawls links in Gmail

Tags: googlebot, email, gmail

We faced a strange issue - within a few-hour window, lots of links in the emails were crawled by Google (Google Bot IP addresses were used).

When looking for information on the internet, there is nothing about Gmail crawling.

Few days after that we noticed, that email deliverability dropped, so maybe Gmail was somehow checking the links?

Has any experienced anything like that or where to find more information?

Answer (score 1):

*A* GoogleBot scanned those links, it wasn't necessarily the same one used for spidering websites.

> **Click-time link protections in third-party email clients**
> Because links to malicious websites can be sent in emails, Google adds link protection for all official Gmail clients (web, Android, and iPhone & iPad). Some of these protections are now available for some users that use a third-party email application (IMAP client).
> For these users, clicking a link in a recent message starts a malicious link check. If nothing malicious is detected, the user is taken to the destination. For older messages, a window might appear, requiring a tap or click to open the link.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10173182?hl=en

As to why it might have affected your email deliverability: How trustworthy is the website you're linking to?

Comment: That could not be the case, since we received much more clicks than usual in that period.

Website - nothing that would fall in some sort of bad categories. No bought email lists or some other shady tricks were used as well.

Comment: You said the email deliverability dropped. If Google found that something about the link was questionable or the emails were unsolicited/unwanted, that would affect the deliverability of the emails to gmail, even if that was an unfair judgement. It wouldn't affect organic or any other traffic to your site.

Comment: I am speaking only about the traffic within the scope of emails, not taking into account any other sources.

There was a 10x more traffic in that time frame, all coming from the google bot addresses and clicking links which are sent to the email.